# 'pip install' fails for every package

Tags: python, pip

First, sorry to raise such common issue, as I saw there are plenty of posts with similar issue, but yet I didn't find solution.

Every package I'm trying to install I'm getting the same error.

For example:
pip install flask   (tried also **pip3** instead)

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask
```

I was using python 3.7.X and was able to install packages before (~year ago), but today start getting those errors. I tried uninstall python and install the latest version:

Python 3.9.1

pip 20.2.3

(window 8.1)

I checked the connection by running "$ curl https://pypi.org" and doesn't see any error.
Tried to set timeout of 60 seconds but same error.

What else I can check?

Comment: are you sure that there is a flask built for python 3.9 yet? I don't think there is

Comment: Don't know. how i can check? I'm getting the same error for any package. Is there any specific package that I should check?

Comment: Could you check whether there are multiple versions of Python on your machine?

Comment: I uninstall the previous version, and then download and install the latest version. If I looked now at the install application I see only the latest version (3.9.1)

Comment: I would look at either the documenting for flask or its page on pipit.org

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has similar issue - I got answer in git issue
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9508

"it seem to be something with IPv6."

Solution:
open the HOSTS file, which is located at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc, in notepad running as Administrator.
Than just add 2 lines at the end:

151.101.0.223 pypi.org
151.101.1.63 files.pythonhosted.org